# PC can't boot. Strange flashing screen

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, bsod, nvidia-quadro

I am running the Windows 8 64 bit consumer preview on a virtual drive on a Lenovo Thinkpad W510 that natively runs Windows 7 Ultimate.
This has been working for about a month.  It has been fine, though I would occasionally get a BSOD displaying INTERNAL_VIDEO_SCHEDULER_ERROR.
Recently, it what I believed would be the solution to this problem, I updated my video card driver (Nvidia Quadro FX 880m).
Next time I tried to boot up, I made it to the Windows 8 dual boot os choice screen as normal.
However, when I choose an OS (8,7, or the advanced options choice), I am met at first with a blank screen, and then, the screen begins to flash about every second where the backround switches between different shades of grey, and the normal Windows blue.  It keeps flashing, and I can see my normal mouse pointer (not flashing), until I restart or sometimes (only on Win 8), I get a blue screen.  This time the error states SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION win32k.sys.  And crash.
I've managed to get into the system at the command prompt with safe mode, but I'm not sure what the best course of action is here.  I need nothing on Windows 8 and would be happy to remove it, but I want to make sure I do it properly.
Any ideas on what the best course of action is?

Comment: At boot press F8 and select `Enable VGA Mode` instead of command prompt, then uninstall nvidia drivers and get new one from lenovo `thinkvantage system update` or from nvidia site, pick `whql variant` for your card.

Comment: This is what I would've done - but I was wrong about being safe mode - I was actually in the recovery console, thus I could not do this.  However, I did solve it, and I will update with the solution.  Thanks for your help